# Python Aiohttp mutliple requests with separate timeout

Tags: python, aiohttp

There are dozens of webpages I want to scrape. I want to make sure if the request for a specific site takes longer than 5 seconds (which is specified below as `timeout`) than the process will just return an error for that website.

In the example below, I try four websites, namely, Google, Python, Facebook and a broken link. If the request is successful with a status code of 200 then it will return a string of `'good'`, otherwise it will return an error message.

Ideally, it should only throw me an error for the final broken link. Instead, it only manages to reach the first website in time and gives me the following:

```
['good', ServerTimeoutError('Connection timeout to host https://python.org/'), ServerTimeoutError('Connection timeout to host https://www.facebook.com/'), ServerTimeoutError('Connection timeout to host http://www.googlesr2332.com')]
```

I know I might have done something wrong with the timeout setting. Seems like the timeout is applied on all of the links instead of each link separately.  Anyone has any idea how I could apply timeout for each individual link?

Example code:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(connect=5)

async def fetch(session, url):
    start = time.time()
    try:
        async with session.get(url,timeout=timeout) as response:
            if response.status != 200:
                response.raise_for_status()
            print(f"Connecting to {url}")
            print(f"Status: {response.status}")
            print(f"Content-type:{response.headers['content-type']}")
            reponse_text = await response.text()
            print(url, ": ", time.time() - start)
            return 'good'
    except Exception as e:
        return e

async def fetch_all(session, urls):
    tasks = []
    for url in urls:
        task = asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url))
        tasks.append(task)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print('Results:')
    return results

async def main():    
    urls = ['http://www.google.com',
    'http://python.org',
    'http://www.facebook.com',
    'http://www.googlesr2332.com'] #, 'http://www.googlesr2332.com'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        htmls = await fetch_all(session, urls)
        print(htmls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code, and it works.

```
(base) xx>python test.py
Connecting to http://www.google.com
Status: 200
Content-type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
http://www.google.com :  0.26312708854675293
Connecting to http://www.facebook.com
Status: 200
Content-type:text/html; charset="utf-8"
http://www.facebook.com :  0.5257956981658936
Connecting to http://python.org
Status: 200
Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
http://python.org :  0.9379258155822754
Results:
['good', 'good', 'good', 

ClientConnectorError(ConnectionKey(host='www.googlesr2332.com', port=80, is_ssl=False, ssl=None, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None, proxy_headers_hash=None), gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))]
```

Windows 10, using conda with python 3.8.3:

```
aiocache==0.11.1
aiofiles==0.6.0
aiohttp==3.7.3
aiohttp-cors==0.7.0
aiologger==0.6.0
aioredis==1.3.1
```